# System Error &H80004015 (-2147467243). The class is configured to run as a security id different from the caller

Tags: vb6

When try to debug the VB dll Using Visual Studio 6.0 , I am getting the the following error. Can you any one tell me what needs to be done for this?

> System Error &H80004015 (-2147467243).
>   The class is configured to run as a
>   security id different from the caller

Comment: windows XP Sp3 , debugging dll i am getting this error?

Comment: All of a sudden i am getting this error while running my vb6.0 project! nothing solves it!

Answer (score 7):

I have had the same problem.
Created a few ActiveX DLLs and put the binaries into a COM+ Application, which runs under a specific account (not mine). Then I use these components inside ASP script pages using Server.CreateObject().
If I load the source code into VB for debugging and try to run it ("Start with Full Compile") I get this error message.
The cause of this is that the account registered in the COM+ Application differs from my own account from which I try to run.
Solution for this particular case is to Shutdown the COM+ Application and remove the components. When finished debugging, compile the set of DLLs and put them back to the COM+ application.

Hope someone is helped by this :-)

Comment: Brilliant - solved it for me. I'd trawled through *a lot* of old forums - all mentioning the 'Winlogon Shell' link, none of which had followup on the expected value. Hosting the assembly in COM+ simultaneously will stop it running as described.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to unreference the dll in the Visual Basic project (`Project Menu -> References`), close the dialog box and reference it once again. I ran the project and everything is working again. I did not have to edit the windows registry.

Answer (score 1):

There's a knowledge base article that seems to apply to your situation:

**[PRB: System Error Message "&H80004015" When You Run ActiveX DLL in Visual Basic IDE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/228487)**

> **Cause:** When Visual Basic runs an ActiveX DLL from the IDE, it calls the `CoRegisterClassObject` application programming interface (API) to temporarily register the server. This creates the AppId and specifies it to run in the Interactive User context.
>
> This problem occurs because of a bug in the Microsoft OLE Libraries 4.0, which are included with the Microsoft Platform Software Development Kit (SDK). `CoRegisterClassObject` fails with the error message that is listed in the "Symptoms" section of this article under the following conditions:
>
> - If the ActiveX server that calls the API is set to run by using the Interactive User identity.
>
>   -and-
> - The string that is associated with the following registry key contains any value other than a single valid executable name for the shell process:
>
>   ```
>   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon Shell=
>   ```
>
>   Under Microsoft Windows 2000, this error occurs when the Certification Authority service does not start.
>
> **Resolution:** Make sure that the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon Shell=` registry key contains a single valid executable name for the shell process.
>
> To resolve this problem under Windows 2000, you can install the "Client for Microsoft Network" component and then reboot.

Comment: registry key contains a single valid executable name for the shell process.? What is the valid executable name , in my registry i am having Explorer.

Comment: @varadarajan: What does that Registry key say? And do you have the Client for Microsoft Network installed? This would be easier to solve with more information.

Comment: I am running it in Windows XP Sp3 , In that HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon Shell Says "Explorer" is that valid value or not?