# The class is configured to run as a security is different from the caller?

Tags: vb6

I have three Projects

- `A.exe` (References B.dll, C.dll) (Project Type - Standard Exe)
- `B.dll` (References C.dll) (Project Type - ActiveX dll)
- `C.dll` (Project Type - ActiveX dll)

As above I have three different projects. Now when I run project A I want to debug or step into Project B and C, can you please let me know what can be possible solution for VB6.

I have tried creating VB Project group for all of them and tried to run A but it's trying to run B and C as well and getting error like below:

> [image: Error]

I did try adding reference of dll and vbp as well but same getting error.

Can you kindly let me know how to work around on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging VB6 dll from VB6 exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972846/debugging-vb6-dll-from-vb6-exe)

Comment: Did you read the message? It telling you.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20539546/Error-The-Class-configured-to-run-as-a-security-ID-different-from-the-caller.html

Comment: Thank you but there are so many msdn documents reference link which has been removed

Comment: and main problem is when i try to run Exe project it tries to run all three project inside project group. can you let me know what is i am missing ? because my exe project is only as Startup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System Error &H80004015 (-2147467243). The class is configured to run as a security id different from the caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567077/system-error-h80004015-2147467243-the-class-is-configured-to-run-as-a-secur)

Comment: @GSerg I think the real issue is the specific error, the OP's debugging approach seems basically OK to me.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs no. can you tell me i did tried re-referencing dll as well as vbp, can do i need to change something related to registry ?

Comment: @VikenPatel your description of using a group sounded fine. You don't need to register anything in that case. But the error message you posted is extremely uncommon.

Comment: Could be a circlar reference issue (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference#In_computer_programming).  I suggest that you remove the references to the DLLs from each other and instead use VB6's CreateObject function to create any instances of objects. The variables will need to be declared as Object.